# How to output all information of a certain row within a file (Employee number, first name, email, etc) by entering just the employee number?

Tags: list, file, dictionary

I am very lost... After creating the dictionary, I am to prompt the user to enter an employee number. I am then supposed to output all employee information for the specific employee and then prompt the user for another employee number. The file with all the information is called employee_records_small.csv. It includes Emp ID,Name Prefix,First Name,Middle Initial,Last Name,Gender,E Mail,Phone No. ,Place Name,County,City,State,Zip,Region, in that order. Here is what I have so far:

```
    def bulkEMail(emailList):
    print('\n*** RESULTS *** \n')
    for emailInfo in emailList:
        print('Email Info: {} {} {}'.format(
            emailInfo['e mail'],
            emailInfo['first name'],
            emailInfo['last name']))
    return True

fh = None
try:
    fh = open('/Users/etaibally/Desktop/employee_records_small.csv', 'r')
except Exception as err:
    print('file not found', err)
    if fh != None:
        fh.close()
        fh = None

if fh != None:

    # Read the header line
    line = fh.readline()
    line = line.lower()
    line = line.replace(' ,', ',').replace(', ', ',')
    headerItems = line.split(',')

    emailList = {}
    dictKeyA = headerItems[0]
    line = fh.readline()
    while line != '':
        lineItems = line.split(',')

        # Initialize dictionary variable
        emailDict = {}

        # For every CSV value in the input line
        for pos, value in enumerate(lineItems):
            dictKey = headerItems[pos]
            emailDict[dictKey] = value

        # next line
        line = fh.readline()

        EmpID = input('Enter ID#: ')
        ID = emailDict[EmpID]
        print(ID)

    # Close file
    fh.close()

    status = bulkEMail(emailList)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Pandas.
Infact, you can load your csv file to a pandas DataFrame by using the command `data = pandas.read_csv(path to file, index_col=column_number_of_employee_number)`.
Then you can find the employee specific data by doing `data[employee_number]`.

Comment: any way to do this without Pandas? This is for a class assingment

Comment: Otherwise you could create a dictionary of dictionaries. The "outside" dictionary would be used to select the employee by it's number, and the value associated to that would be a list of dict (the ones you have already created). Then you can iterate over it to print everything.